# SELECT from slave and INSERT into master in MySQL

Tags: mysql, php, master-slave-replication

I'm using PHP/Laravel and MySQL databases.

Briefly, I want to use slave databases for reads and master database for writes.

What Laravel config, Laravel package, or database tool do you suggest to handle my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To config Laravel to split reads and writes you can edit `config/database.php` this way:

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'read' => [
            'host' => env('DB_READ_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_READ_DATABASE', ''),
            'username' => env('DB_READ_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_READ_PASSWORD', ''),
        ],
        'write' => [
            'host' => env('DB_WRITE_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_WRITE_DATABASE', ''),
            'username' => env('DB_WRITE_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_WRITE_PASSWORD', ''),
        ],
    ],

    //...
]
```

As for the point which @rick-james mentioned you can use MySQL Router to balance requests between some databases so you can use both master and slave for reads.

Answer (score 2):

Dangerous. Read about "Critical Read". If you blindly send all `SELECTs` to a Slave, you could screw up transactions on the master. Or you could miss data when replication is "behind".

Instead, modify your application to connect to either the Master or to some Slave, based on whether it is safe to get the data just from a Slave.

Comment: just for not create similar answer - often just move report loading from Master to Slave resolve a lot of narrow necks on the Master. For re-direct query You can use or ProxySQL or MaxScale or few other load balancer, which all work +- similar, one port point to Master, other to Slave (like 3306, 3307)

Comment: Sure, moving entire clients (such as report-writers, query-only UIs, etc) to the Slave is simple, safe, and useful.

Comment: Can you please provide some insight into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849283/fetch-inserted-data-in-master-slave-model ?

Comment: The link is now https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175960/fetch-just-inserted-data-in-master-slave-model .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [ProxySQL](http://www.proxysql.com/) for this use case. 
https://proxysql.blogspot.com/2015/09/proxysql-tutorial-setup-in-mysql.html scroll down to the part where it says Read-Write split.