# Created RDS db-instance Replica successfully, now how to connect it with server

Tags: mysql, replication, performance, amazon-rds

I had created AWS RDS, MySQL db-instance successfully with the help of [Github Pages Documentation](https://github.com/18F/openFEC/wiki/Creating-and-configuring-a-read-replica-in-Amazon-RDS). Thanks a lot *18F/OpenFEC Project*.

Now, Instead of [Route 53 configuration for network connectivity](https://github.com/18F/openFEC/wiki/Creating-and-configuring-a-read-replica-in-Amazon-RDS#route-53-configuration-for-network-connectivity), I want to configure directly through Godaddy DNS Manager. Because already a subdomain is configured for a production server with RDS db-instance endpoints.

I can create another subdomain at DNS Manager with Replica db-instance's end points. But, how to achieve connection on both db-instance as well as replica-db-instance.

Please guide me, to manage traffic of db query without updating that production app.

Comment: When doing "read-write splitting" beware of the "critical read" problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting read error: "Read Replica Replication Error - SQLError: 1194, reason: Error Table login is marked as crashed and should be repaired on query. Default database: database-name. Query: update login set is_login=0 where is_login=1 and updated_on 2017-07-16 11:05:16"

Comment: What engine are you using for that table?  Please don't use MyISAM.  Meanwhile, do `CHECK TABLE` and, if indicated, `REPAIR TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is called **Read/Write Splitting**.   This is not a capability directly provided either by MySQL Server itself, or by RDS for MYSQL. It is an advanced technique for which there are no magic solutions, as I have mentioned [elsewhere](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/175962/11651).

If you are not modifying your application (and assuming your framework does not have such functionality built-in, which is a reasonably safe assumption), you will need to deploy one or more read/write splitting proxy servers to divert each query to the correct target as appropriate.

Examples of software with this capability are [MariaDB MaxScale](https://mariadb.com/products/technology/maxscale) and [ProxySQL](http://www.proxysql.com).